# You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page

Tags: wordpress

I recently set up a local copy of Wordpress, added some content and created a child theme. Then I moved it to my webserver, changed the config file, changed the "localhost" occurences in my SQL file to my online URL. I also changed my database prefix from what I had locally on all tables and in the config file.

Everything works well on the outside. But then as I log-in is get the:
`You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.`

**Update:**
Even my local install of wordpress is giving me the same problem.

---

Comment: The solution is located here: [Custom Wordpress Plugin: Sufficient Privelages Error][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18136064/custom-wordpress-3-5-2-plugin-you-do-not-have-sufficient-permissions-to-access/18136893#18136893

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First thing to do is check your directory permissions. Generally, directories should be 755, files should be 644. See [Changing File Permissions « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions) and [Hardening WordPress « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress#File_permissions).

Also,  since you changed your DB table prefix, see this: [How to solve ‘You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.’ in WordPress.](http://beconfused.com/2007/08/28/how-to-solve-you-do-not-have-sufficient-permissions-to-access-this-page-in-wordpress/)

Comment: Thanks you, the Be Confused post helped!

Answer (score 1):

The most common cause is an upgrade that didn’t complete.
Check it ;-)